# Read time and position data from csv file to rotate game object - Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a csv file that contains a time vector in column 1 (time) and a vector with angles in column 2 (pitch).  The csv looks like this:

```
time,pitch
0.001,0.0017778
0.002,0.0035556
0.003,0.0053333
0.004,0.0071111
0.005,0.0088889
0.006,0.010667
0.007,0.012444
0.008,0.014222
...
220.000,0
```

The increment of the time vector is in ms and the data range until 220 seconds (so 220000 data points).

As soon as I press the R key, an object should start rotating around ist x axis along the angles defined in "pitch" of the csv file. The rotation speed should correspond to "time" in the csv file. So after 1ms the angle should 0.00177, after 2 ms 0.00355, after 3 ms 0.00533 and so on… The complete trajectory should therefore be completed after 220 seconds (220000 data points sampled at 1000 Hz).

I have started a script to complete this task that looks like this:

```csharp
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Globalization;

public class CsvReader : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextAsset csvFile;

    // Create arrays to store the values in "time" and "pitch" columns
    float[] timeArray = new float[220000];
    float[] pitchArray = new float[220000];
    int i = 0;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.R))
        {
            StartCoroutine(ReadCsv());
        }

    }

    IEnumerator ReadCsv()
    {
        string[] records = csvFile.text.Split('\n');

        for (int i = 1; i < records.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] fields = records[i].Split(',');

            // Store the values in "time" and "pitch" columns in separate arrays
            timeArray[i] = float.Parse(fields[0], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            pitchArray[i] = float.Parse(fields[1], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            Debug.Log(pitchArray[i]);

            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(pitchArray[i], 0f, 0f);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.001f); // this is the delay between each position change (1 ms)
        }
    }
}
```

I assigned the script to an object but the rotation of the object is way too slow and i cant figure out a solution by myself. I would be very grateful if anyone has any advice!

Answer (score 0):

You do not have CSV data separated by commas.  Date is fixed with.  Try folloiwing

```
   public class CsvReader 
    {
        // Create arrays to store the values in "time" and "pitch" columns
        List<float> timeArray { get; set; }
        List<float> pitchArray { get; set; }

        public CsvReader(string filename)
        {
            timeArray = new List<float>();
            pitchArray = new List<float>();

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename);
            string line = "";
            int lineNumber = 0;
            while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                lineNumber++;
                if(lineNumber > 1)
                {
                    string[] columns = line.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    timeArray.Add(float.Parse(columns[0]));
                    pitchArray.Add(float.Parse(columns[1]));
                }

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. The data are indeed separated by commas. I was not careful enough when I copied the data. My problem is not so much to read the data correctly, but to move the object at each time frame to the corresponding value in „pitch".

Answer (score 0):

> This is happening due to **fps (frames per second)** limitation.

For example to show all the `pitch` value rotation from `0.001 ms` to `1.000 ms` you need atleast `1000 fps`. As `WaitForSeconds()` yields per frame and you are trying to yield for `0.001 sec` it is not able to go that low instead switching respective to the fps it is getting.

One approach that might work hypothetically is to change the `targetFrameRate` but that will work on a device capable of rendering `1000 fps`.

```csharp
Application.targetFrameRate = 1000;
```

Comment: Thanks @Sujoy for your comment. Unfortunatelly your suggestions do not alter the outcome compared to my initial script. In fact, when i change the value for `rotationSpeed` the pitching velocity of the game object does not change. Also note that its probably not necessary to calculate time difference between data points, as this difference is fixed (1 millisecond). Somehow it apperas to me as if Unity is just looping to slow through the values...

Comment: Can you share the csv file so I can try properly to get you a solution ?

Comment: With pleasure! Thank you for the offer. You can download the file from this [Link to csv file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ib4brwbl7zqusuc/vr_stim_5.csv?dl=0). The csv uses comma as delimiter. There are also data in columns three to six, but i am only ionterested in column 1 (time) and column 2 (pitch).

Comment: I have updated the code with your code only and fixed an issue from my side, have a look. The issue was that I was not using the `rotationSpeed`.

Comment: This is not working as it alters the original pitch values by the factor of `rotationSpeed`. However, the pitch values are to remain as they are stored in the csv file. The bottom line is that I just want a game object to move along the data row pitch in the csv file within exactly 220 seconds.

Comment: I have updated my answer after proper testing and going through unity API limitation and issues. Sorry for not having an exact answer for you.